# Checkboxs: ticking me off!

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

this is a small, **but very annoying**, glitch in my form.

I have a checkbox, that if clicked displays others checkboxes and input fields for the user to add more information. If this trigger checkbox is unclicked, the extra options dissapear.

However (the plot thickens), if another checkbox is checked in the form, the trigger checkbox can be checked and the extra options appear, **but if unchecked the extra option won't dissapear!**

(Sorry that was long winded, but i wanted to be clear!)

Here is my simple Jquery code:

```
$(function() {

    var boxes = $('.obstruct-opt');
    boxes.hide();

    var ob = $('li.obstructionOptions').children().eq(0);

    ob.change(function() {
    if ($('$(this):checked').val()) {
        boxes.show();
    }
    else {
        boxes.hide();
    }
    });

});
```

I have tried different ways of checking if the trigger is checked or not, but any suggestions are welcome.

**Edit**
HTML as requested: (although simplified as my ASP.Net repeater control generated it)

```
<ul>
<li class="obstructionOptions">                   

<span>
<input id="Obstruction" type="checkbox" name="Obstruction" />
<label for="Obstruction">Obstruction</label>
</span>

<span class="obstruct-opt">
<input id="WeatherProof" type="checkbox" name="WeatherProof"/>
<label for="WeatherProof">WeatherProof</label>
</span>

<span class="obstruct-opt">
<input id="WeatherProofFlap" type="checkbox" name="WeatherProofFlap"/>
</span>

</li>

<li class="obstruct-opt">
<span>Obstruction Notes</span>
<textarea name="ObstructionNotes" rows="7" cols="50" id="ObstructionNotes"/>           
</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps!

**Update:**
substituting the if condition to

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

doesn't trigger anything, no appearing or disappearing acts in sight.
Thanks for the suggestion tho, maybe with my html you can discern why?

**Update**
Ok after posting my HTML i realised ASP.Net has been stitching me up!
As you can see i select the 'ob' object as the first child, but the first child is a generated span! ASP has been wrapping my checkboxes in spans all this time and i never suspected! shrewd!

I have used this code in the end:

```
  $('ul li.obstructionOptions span').children().eq(0).click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                boxes.show();
            }
            else {
                boxes.hide();
            }
    });
```

Thank you to adamantium as this solved the prod perfectly!

**Problem Solved!**

Do not to trust ASP.Net with my markup!!!

Comment: if `ob` is the checkbox element, you might also consider using `click` as opposed to `change` due to differences cross-browser as to when the `change` event is raised.

Comment: I have thanks! and re-wrote my update to include your answer! thanks for the online demo too! Great Job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about replacing

```
if ($('$(this):checked').val())
```

with

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

[is](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is)

> Checks the current selection against
>   an expression and returns true, if at
>   least one element of the selection
>   fits the given expression.

***Edit:***
Replace

```
var ob = $('li.obstructionOptions').children().eq(0);
```

with

```
var ob = $('ul li.obstructionOptions span').children().eq(0);
```

and

```
<textarea name="ObstructionNotes" rows="7" cols="50" id="ObstructionNotes"/>
```

with

```
<textarea name="ObstructionNotes" rows="7" cols="50" id="ObstructionNotes"></textarea>
```

and your code works fine.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/enuba)

Comment: Thanks! You posted this as i was writing my third update, as i saw the prob when i looked at the generated markup, thank you for your answer, that's a better way to select the span!!! another update on the way!

Answer (score 2):

It might have something to do with this line:

```
if ($('$(this):checked').val()) {
```

AFAIK, that won't do anything useful. You probably want this:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: Thanks, you have the right code, but i was selecting the trigger wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob.change(
```

A checkbox's `onchange` doesn't fire in IE until it's unfocused. For this reason it's usual to use `onclick` instead.

```
$('$(this):checked').val()
```

Doesn't work for two reasons. Firstly, you've included `$(this)` as part of the string. A dollar and brackets don't mean anything to selectors so jQuery won't match anything. You've already got the `this` object you want; you don't need to select anything more. Secondly, `val()` on a checkbox gets the value of that checkbox, not whether it is checked or not. This is the `value` attribute, or `on` if you haven't specified one.

Whilst you could test for checkedness using `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`, it's more readable and much quicker to just use the standard DOM `checked` property. You don't *have* to shoehorn everything you do into jQuery.

```
ob.click(function() {
    if (this.checked)
        boxes.show();
    else
        boxes.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it originally didn't work as in my update the html was generating obscurley, but thanks for your suggestion on selecting and using standard DOM properties, i haven't been on jquery too long and not often enough and i really liked the cleaness this gave it!